# Is there a command to flip the state of a BOOLean (iOS)

Tags: ios, boolean

If I have a BOOL that has a state of YES or NO, is there a command to flip its state?

Obviously foo=!foo; doesn't apply.

Comment: why does foo=!foo no apply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Obviously foo=!foo; doesn't apply.

`foo = !foo` **does** apply.

---

`NO` example:

```
BOOL foo = NO;
foo = !foo;
...foo equals YES...
```

And for any value other than `NO`:

```
BOOL foo = YES; // -3 or YES or 100
foo = !foo;
...foo equals NO...
```

---

If you find an API which does not return `YES` or `NO`, file a bug report. You wouldn't see that from Apple, but some people have taken advantage of the ability to store numbers other than `YES` or `NO` in a `BOOL` (which is a `signed char` -- it predates C's `bool`). If needed, you can reduce a `BOOL` to `YES` or `NO` using `!!foo`, `(bool)foo`, or `bool f = foo;`. I favor the last; `bool` variables.

Comment: I have my BOOL setup as an iVar. WHen I tired foo = !foo; I gte three errors: 1) Implicit convercion of int to NSSet is disclaimer is disallowed with ARC 2) Incompatible integer pointer assigning to NSSet _strong from int; and 3) Local declaration of foo hides instance variable. Hence my comment about foo=!foo not working which is what I would normally use.

Comment: Apologies - I'd repeated a variable name hence the compiler and author getting confused. Sorry for wasting your time.